# Using Social Business Toolkit against IBM Smartcloud

Tags: javascript, ibm-sbt, ibm-connections

If I look at the SBT Playground Site on greenhouse I can find Javascript API and Smartcloud as an option. But all javascript references will then point to greenhouse, and that doesn't seams like a good idea for production.

If I install the same Playground database with SBT on a Domino server I don't get smartcloud as an option.

Can I make a locally installed playground work with SmartCloud ?
Any setup guides for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described by Paul. 
in the playground application, select the top dropdown for environment and choose value custom and click on the pen.

[image]

Select smartcloud for social business
Select basic authentication

[image]

This should give you the option to try out the SBT against IBM Smart Cloud.

Click on Authentication and SmartClound OAuth 1.0a and login 
The basic Auth option doesn't work out of the box

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, you just need to use the right endpoint when you access the smartcloud services.
When you do the setup with Environments, you can configure/use SmartCloudOA2 to access the backend services.

Comment: Do I only write SmartCloudOA2 as the end point or do I need some special URL?
Is there any example showing this ?

Comment: create a new environment via the web UI, it'll ask you if you want a smartcloud environment in the wizard.  I document it in a blog here - http://bastide.org/2014/10/23/first-time-through-bss-and-api-explorer-tip/

Comment: If I follow your guide on my local server I get
Unhandled error: TypeError: config.findEndpoint(...) is undefined
and the javascript code says var ep = config.findEndpoint("smartcloudBasic"); as the endpoint

Comment: you can use smartcloudOA2 as the endpoint in your playground.